# Make class of type U where U can be any protocol

Tags: swift, generics

Because of our existing architecture and project requirements, I have a specific need (I don't think going into too much detail is relevant to this question).

Is it possible to have a class of generic type U where U can be any type of protocol? Here's 2 attempts on what I'd like to achieve. Of course, neither compile.

```
class BaseService<T> where T.Type == Protocol.Type {

}
extension BaseService: T {}
// error: Inheritance from non-protocol type 'T'
```

or

```
protocol BaseServiceProtocol: class {}

class BaseService<T>: T where T == BaseServiceProtocol {
// error: Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'T' non-generic
}
```

Swift complains that T is not a class nor a protocol and thus BaseService can't inherit from it.

Is this something possible? Having this would mean I could require my services to be injected as their protocol but in my class I would have access to a concrete instance.

Thank you for any tips. If this is not possible (yet), an explanation would be awesome too.

**EDIT**

My objective is to be able to have this at the call site:

```
let myService: BaseService<AwesomeServiceProtocol>
```

Where myService is a concrete class that responds to a protocol.

Comment: Why would disallowing classes be desirable?

Comment: Services are injected as protocols. It makes for easier testing. I'm not saying we're disallowing classes, I'm simply saying we work another way.

Comment: "A protocol" is not a type in Swift that you can talk about. A protocol describes a type, it is not a type itself. (Protocols without associated types have an implicit existential which is a type, but this is a complicated topic which doesn't change the basic answer, which is "no.") You may find the following useful for your design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE

Comment: Voted down for confusing mentions of `U` and `BaseService`. Seems like it was written too much for you and not another person.

Comment: Sorry Jessy, there shouldn't be any mention of ReactService. I fixed it to be BaseService. Where I think it can be useful to everyone, it is the question of generics and protocols in Swift. I hope this clarifies my intentions.